# Remove authorisation required for script on Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I run a few bound scripts on Google Sheets I create for users, due to the script functions all require authorisation.

The scripts run from buttons inserted on the spreadsheet itself. I want to remove the authorisation procces so that anonymous users can run the script - I have tried deploying the script as a web app but this hasn't worked.

Has anyone got any ideas what I can do to create these scripts so that anyone can run the script without having to authorise through a Google account please?

Many thanks

P.S. don't suggest that I get all users to create Google accounts as that just isn't going to happen! :-)

Comment: With a webapp deploy it to run as you and allow anyone including anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to make users, who don't login to Google, run the container-bound script of Spreadsheet by clicking a button on Spreadsheet.
- You want to make users run the script without the authorization.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, users as anyone who don't login to Google cannot run the script by the clicking a button put on Spreadsheet. This has already mentioned in your question. This situation is the same with the custom menu.

So in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround.

In this workaround, the OnEdit event trigger is used. From your question, I thought that your script might include the methods for requiring to authorize the scopes. So here, the OnEdit event trigger is used as the installable trigger. When the script is run by the OnEdit event trigger, the script is run as the owner. When you install the OnEdit event trigger as the installable trigger, the authorization process is run. So when users use this script, the authorization process is not required.

### Usage:

In order to use this sample script, please do the following flow.

1. Copy and paste the following script by including your script to the script editor.
2. [Install the OnEdit event trigger to `installedOnEdit` as the installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).
3. **A checkbox is used as the button for executing the script. In order to execute the script, as a test case, please put a checkbox to the cell "A1".**

#### Sample script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    var range = e.range;
    try {
      if (range.getA1Notation() == "A1" && e.value == "TRUE") {


        // Please put your script here.


      }
    } catch(err) {
      throw new Error(err)
    } finally {
      range.uncheck();
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this script, when you check the checkbox, the script in the if statement is run. And when the script is finished, the checkbox is unchecked by `e.range.uncheck()`. By this, the checkbox is back to standby.
- By LockService, the exclusive processing of the script is run.
- If the process time of your script is over 10 seconds, please modify `lock.tryLock(10000)`.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike - looks like you have the answer!  I have copied that script but I get the following error:

```TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")```

Any ideas?

Comment: can also confirm when changing the cell location of which the checkbox goes, do I change this line ```if (range.getA1Notation() == "A1" && e.value == "TRUE") {``` to ```if (range.getF1Notation() == "F1" && e.value == "TRUE") {``` - many thanks

Comment: @Gav Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that the reason of the error is that you directly run the function `installedOnEdit` with the script editor. Please read the section of "Usage:". And when you run the script, please check the checkbox at the cell "A1". At first, please confirm whether the script works. This answer is a workaround for running a script with anyone. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.