# create Google Sheet database accessed by different users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've built a spreadsheet as a form by google script with one button which updates a database(a different sheet) according to the form - `btn_pressed()`.

I want to authorize any google account I give access to - to use the form (activate the google script code), and update the database and send mail (part of the `btn_pressed()` process).

should I publish the script as a web app? or there's another way to do what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `the form`. Is it a Google Form attached to your Spreadsheet? Or do you refer to a [UI element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)? Please clarify that and provide the relevant code (free of sensitive information of course).

Comment: @Iamblichus its UI element. a spreadsheet which looks like a form with an activation button that runs google scripts code

Comment: As explained in Tanaike's answer in the link provided by Gav, you can only do this via an installable trigger, which asks for authorization when it is installed, not when it is used. Please take into account, though, that the email will be sent by the account that installed the trigger, not by the one currently using the spreadsheet. And of course, you could publish a web app if this behaviour doesn't convince you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to automatically authorise the script for other users when they come to run the script?

I recently learnt you can only do this with certain triggers such as onOpen() out onEdit(), there is a way round this though.  Please see the following link as i asked the question on here myself!

[Remove authorisation required for script on Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461673/remove-authorisation-required-for-script-on-google-sheets)

I trust that helps